# Threads ends when run finish?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to know if a thread in java closes itself when run method ends.

I mean, I have a new thread declaration:

```
new Thread(new SubmitDataOnBackground(handler.getIDValue(), data, this.context)).start();
```

And then, in SubmitDataOnBackground I have this run method:

```
public void run() {
    SubmitDataHandler submit = new SubmitDataHandler(ID, data, this.context);
    submit.buildAndSubmitData();

}
```

After buildandSubmitData finishes, does the thread close itself or I have to add any code somewhere?

I am not sure if I am leaving a new thread opened each time I call this method or it is ok.

My application is a server so it will never ends because it is active the whole time. I just want to know the amount of threads is not outnumbered because it just creates new ones without closing the others when finish.

Comment: Threads will terminate upon completion.  You do not have to manually end/kill them.

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Threads close themselves after the run method has been called. Read this for further information https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

**EDIT:** If you want to avoid this behaviour, I recommend using ThreadPools.

Comment: Ok, I am glad to know that. I want them close themselves so this is the behaviour I need. Anyway, I will read your link to know a bit more

Comment: @Biribu if you want to call the run method a lot of times, it is recommended using ThreadPools, because they keep their threads when the run method is finished. You might want to look into that if you call it a lot

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind and I will try to implement it. I use the thread to save some data in my database, data gets into the server 3 or 4 times per minute so maybe it is a good idea threadpool

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a thread finishes when `run()` method execution ends. You can read more on threads and concurency in general [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)

One tip here - when using multiple threads that are started and finished all the time, it is a good idea to use a thread pool. That is because creating a thread is quite a heavy operation.

Answer (score 2):

Threads are terminated after finishing their jobs (when the execution of `run()` ends). If you want to check, use `isAlive()`.

Comment: Yea ... but what does "after finishing their jobs" mean?  The OP asked about the `run()` method.

Comment: I think of run method as a Thread's job - what else could it be? :)

Comment: What you "think" is not the point.  The purpose of a SO answer is to explain to the OP in terms that he or she is likely to understand.  If he asks about the `run()` method, explain it to him in terms of the `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In order to actually make a Thread stop itself, the process is quite simple. All you need to do is simply let the `run` method run out and return.

```
public void run(){

   // implement your code

   // Just about to return and the Thread will then stop soon after

}
```

**Note** that the thread will not necessarily be declared finished immediately after the run method has finished, as the **Java Virtual Machine** (JVM) still needs to finish it off in the background, but it should terminate completely soon after.

In other words, when a normal Thread (also referred to as a user Thread) is created, it is expected that it will complete its work and not shut down permanetly. The **JVM** will not terminate until all user Threads have finished, or until a call is made to the `System.exit()` method, which terminates the **JVM** abruptly.

**EDIT:** `System.exit()` does not stop the JVM abruptly, it executes all the shutdown hooks first. `Runtime.getRuntime().halt()` stops the JVM without any further processing.

Comment: The question is not about how to stop  a thread.

Comment: I think we are not supposed to use stop() since it is deprecated.

Comment: The `destroy` and `stop` methods were deprecated way back in Java 1.1.  You won't find any *sane* code using them.  So it is really not worth mentioning them.  Besides, that is NOT what the question is about.

Comment: @farukdgn I have already mentioned that `stop()` is deprecated.

Comment: Never mind, I am going to edit the whole answer.

Comment: @Biribu I have edited my answer and I have explained how Thread terminate itself with details.

Comment: System.exit() doesn't terminate the JVM abruptly. Runtime.getRuntime().halt() does.

Comment: @Distjubo Thank you for letting me know that. I learn something new about the JDK every day :) . See EDIT.

Comment: @Chaker Mallek Even System.exit() always  exits. But the difference is, that System.exit() will call all the shutdown hooks first.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you @Distjubo

Answer (score 0):

Yes, threads are terminated after finishing their specified jobs (sequence of instructions) in `run()` method.
However, the thread object that has been created still exists, allowing you call it again with `Thread.start()` to create a new Thread.

If you want to be sure that your thread run method ends before continuing doing something more, try to use the method `Thread.join()` in the same place where you are working with threads.

Read this for further information about that:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29